# How to align the text in the button to the center?

Tags: css, primefaces

I struggle to this issue for a long time, and try many solutions that similar topic in the stackOverflow, but cannot resolve my problem.
Here is my code:

```
<p:commandButton id="verifyButtonId" value="Verify" ajax="true" actionListener="#{LocationEditBean.verifyAccess}" update="panelVerifyMessageId" style="height:25px; line-height:25px; vertical-align:middle;" rendered="#{LocationEditBean.showVerify}">
                                <f:param value="#{LocationEditBean.classifiedObject.ID}" name="editId"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
```

The text in the commandButton cannot align to the vertical center. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you try vertical-align:center; and text-align:center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can try adding the following style to your button:

style=
  "font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  min-width: 90px;
  padding:5px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response Karthi. It seems cannot work, since I have to set the height as my expect, but not default height.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nathan16185/2xdgX/                                 - please look at the fiddle. Text is in the middle only..

Comment: Thanks karthi, your answer leads me to the key point. I should change the font size too once I change the height of button. Add "font-size: 75% !important" to the style attribut.